# Sencha Touch - View / Store / Model Proxy Issue

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2-proxy

I am pretty new to Sencha. Just trying to work out why the way I am currently doing my View / Store / Model for my project is not working ><

I am trying to get the product list to pull from my json, right now it is not really working. Any advice will be appreciated!

Here are the code (Edit, I pasted the wrong code the first time, corrected it >< Sorry):

**View:**

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.ProductsList', {
   extend: 'Ext.DataView',
   xtype: "productslist",

   config: {
    flex:1,
     scrollable: true,

     store: 'Plist',
 itemTpl: '<img src={image} width="90%"><br>{name}'
   }
});
```

**Model**

```
Ext.define('Sencha.model.ProductsList', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'name',
                    type: 'string'
                }, {
                    name: 'image',
                    type: 'string'
                }

            ]

        }
    });
```

**Store**

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    storeId: 'Plist',
    model:'Sencha.model.ProductsList',
    title: 'My Collection',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/products.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'products'
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!!

Additional Info: I threw the three sections together into the view file (and rename `Sencha.model.ProductsList` to `Productslist`, it worked. It is when I separate them into view, store and model, then it stop working. It has something to do with the way I am linking these files.

Anyone with more insight?

Comment: What do you mean by "not really working?" Are you seeing any errors in the console? Is there a reason you are using `Ext.create` rather than `Ext.define` for the store?

Comment: I have also tried to use `Ext.define('Sencha.store.ProductsList',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store'.....` It basically yield thesame result. The stuff was working when I directly inject the data in View with `data` tag, but now with store and model it doesn't work. I feel like it is the problem in how I am calling the store...? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Try putting the data inline in the store. At least then you will know if the problem is loading the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'products'
}
```

should be:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty: 'products'
}
```

Also,

```
itemTpl: '<img src={image} width="90%"><br>{name}'
```

should have quotes around `{image}`:

```
itemTpl: '<img src="{image}" width="90%"><br>{name}'
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I have switched to inline data:

`Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    storeId: 'Plist',
    model:'Sencha.model.ProductsList',
    data: {
            id: 'ProductsList',
            access: 'public'
            },
    fields: [
            {name: 'Item 1', image: 'images/cosmetics.jpg'},
            {name: 'Item 2', image: 'images/cosmetics.jpg'},
            {name: 'Item 3', image: 'images/cosmetics.jpg'},
            {name: 'Item 4', image: 'images/cosmetics.jpg'}

        ]
}
});`

It doesn't work so the call proxy is not the issue. ><

Comment: I just threw all three parts into the view file, and rename the `Sencha.model.ProductsList` to `Productslist`, and it works fine. It is how I am setting the files up that is causing the issue, and idea? Thanks!

Comment: Again, looking at the console might help. Maybe you forgot to add one of the files to app.js?